# Is Rust entirely independent of the OS and C?

Tags: c, rust

Is Rust entirely independent of other languages and OSs like C is, or is it not?

Comment: C11 introduced `<threads.h>` and a memory model supporting concurrency. And I see no reason whatoever to "limit the use of the standard library" (which usually results in you *reimplementing* those parts of the standard library).

Comment: Why should you never use concurrency and limit use of the standard library in C? Your premise is strange, to say the least. If you're writing an OS from scratch, you're responsible for *providing* the standard library, but that doesn't mean you can't use it once you've made it.

Comment: Also, every programming language *eventually* has to rely on the OS kernel to do certain things, like accessing files to name just one example. That interfacting with the OS kernel virtually always uses some kind of C interfacing, because C is the *lingua franca* of programming. You're facing a catch-22 if you want to design an OS "independent of C".

Answer (score 1):

> Is Rust entirely independent of the OS and C?

Rust normally relies on the host system to support things like I/O. But it can be independent.

For OS development, you would use [no_std](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/intro/no-std.html): an environment for Rust without host support. This environment includes the [core](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/) library (a subset of the std library) with no threads, no dynamic memory, no I/O. Implementing those would be part of developing the OS.

Comment: Of note, I believe you can do something similar with C.

Comment: @ikegami: What, you think people can use C for operating systems? Who ever heard of such a thing?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil :) Yeah "I believe" might be a bit of an understatement.

Answer (score 1):

> In C, there are a few constraints you should respect, such as not using any concurrency, limiting the use of the standard library, and such.

Not exactly. In freestanding C, there are a few standard library facilities that are guaranteed to be available.

Further, whether there may be several threads of execution is implementation-defined. When developing the usual OS with SMP etc, you will need a freestanding implementation with such support.

> In Rust however, I have found that you should explicitly specify certain parts of your code to use C's linking implementation rather than Rust's, and taking many more aspects of your programming behaviour into consideration.

Not exactly either. One can program an operating system using only Rust's ABI to interface with assembly files and other bits. The problem is that such ABI is not going to be stable for the foreseeable future. Therefore, if you are willing to follow the changes, you could do it. But it is simpler to use C's instead.

Another possibility to avoid dealing with an ABI is trying to do everything with inline assembly instead.

> So my question is, is Rust entirely independent of other languages and OSs like C is, or is it not?

Both can be, for freestanding purposes.

Comment: @skevula I was referring to the Rust ABI. Whether other object files are written in assembly or not is outside Rust scope; it does not make sense to talk about "stable" or "unstable" for that.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you.

Comment: @skevula C is a standard, there are many implementations. Each may define their own ABI. I am not sure what you mean by "*why can't Rust do it?*". Rust does it the same way: it defines an ABI too (but such ABI is not meant to be frozen, that is the issue). You're welcome! :-)

Comment: @skevula Yes, Rust can indeed be used independently just as C can, that is true. It is also true that using your C implementation's ABI is simpler than any Rust's ABI (due to language features). But "Assembly" does not have an ABI, it is just assembly; you can use any ABI. Happy new year!

Comment: Maybe you mean Rust’s API (Application Programming Interface), a set of routines available in Rust for programming various things (performing various functions). ABI’s are Application Binary Interfaces, and they are not per-language. When there are multiple languages involved in the binaries (executable code) of a project, they must use the same application **binary interface**. It is, by definition, how they work together.